# When drawing cards for each produced good, does it include goods produced on windfall worlds?

Tags: race-for-the-galaxy

My friends and I have had disagreements about how one particular kind of production power works in Race for the Galaxy: powers that involve drawing cards for each good produced, e.g.

Diversified Economy:

> draw 1 card for each *kind* of good you produced this phase

Research Labs:

> draw 1 card for each Alien technology good you produced

When combined with powers that produce goods on windfall planets, such as the power of the Produce action card itself, **do you draw cards for goods produced using the 'produce on windfall' powers?**

In part it is that I don't understand what "no power can interrupt another" means in the RFTG rulebook and also because online versions of the games vary with how this applies.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Yes**. Those powers apply to all goods that are produced on your worlds, regardless of *how* they are produced.

Comment: You got this from the rulebook?

Comment: Not as such. There is no division between "produced" and "windfall" worlds, so *all* goods count as "produced". It's just that production (i.e. non-windfall) worlds have a "produce a good" power.

Comment: Argh! `There is no division between "produced" and "windfall" GOODS`

Answer (score 11):

**Yes, you draw a card regardless of what kind of world the good was produced on.** The [rulebook](http://www.riograndegames.com/uploads/Game/Game_240_gameRules.pdf) mentions, (page 7) under Produce, that players who choose **Produce** get to "produce" a good on one Windfall world. It also gives an example of a special power that produces goods on windfall worlds. Since **Research Labs** draws cards for each good of a specific kind produced, and the rules indicate that goods on windfall worlds can be "produced" either as a bonus based on a players chosen action or card effects, you draw a card regardless of whether that good was produced on a halo/solid world.

> Players who chose **Produce**, as a bonus, produce a good (if possible) on one of their windfall worlds that does not already have a good.
>
> Some cards, such as **Genetic Labs**, can also produce goods on windfall worlds (without goods).

**What does "no power can interrupt another" mean?**

What is meant here, is that you should resolve a power/effect completely before applying the results of another power/effect. **Example:** If you have an Alien world (yellow) that allows you to Discard a Card to produce an Alien good, but you have no cards in hand and no way to produce yellow goods. You could draw cards from **Diversified Economy** (for producing goods on other worlds), and then discard one of those cards to produce an Alien good. **This would not entitle you to draw another card from Diversified Economy** for producing another kind of good, because you already resolved it's effects. If you control a **Research Labs** as well though, you could draw a card from it's power by resolving it's effect after Diversified Economy and the "Discard to Produce Good" effect of the Alien world.

Comment: Oh nice explanation of that last part, power interruption